# How do I record a screen cap video of the iPad?

Tags: ipad

I'm looking for a method to record the video without actually filming the device. Does such a method exist?

Comment: It may be possible to do something in the iPad emulator which comes as part of the iPad SDK. It will likely require some significant hacking, though (and you need a mac).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Reflection](http://reflectionapp.com/) (US$15) turns a (Lion or above) Mac into an AirPlay receiver that can handle mirroring.  Once you've got the mirrored display on a Mac, all you need is to capture that video, which is easy.

For example:

1. Start Reflection on the Mac.
2. Turn mirroring on (requires iPad 2 or newer or iPhone 4S or newer), selecting the Mac as the target.
3. Use a video screen capture program (Quicktime Player can do this, but there are lots of more advanced ones if you need more) to record the Reflection window.

**No jailbreaking is required.**

[AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/en) (also US$15) is another application that offers essentially the same functionality as Reflection (and was released slightly afterwards), but is also available for Windows, if you don't have a Mac to do the recording on.

Comment: if the Mac can have that built in, it'd be great

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to jailbreak your iPad, both [Display Recorder](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayrecorder/) and [ScreenRecorder](http://thebigboss.org/screenrecorder) do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to record an iOS screen digitally is to mirror the screen over AirPlay to a computer and record the screen of the computer.

You could also record the HDMI output from an AppleTV but that's usually more costly than picking up a license of [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/).

It does recording for most situations, but I prefer using a second app in my Mac to [record the screen](http://support.airsquirrels.com/article.php?id=31) and you have many more options there.

The simulator isn't an emulator - so you can't just run other apps in Xcode (with the assumption that the particular app you desire to record isn't one that you have the source code to run in simulation). I know you mentioned free trick for recording, but I've not found a free tool that works for decent quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an extra Windows PC with a spare PCI-express slot (and the Windows PC should be moderately fast, anything with multiple cores and a video card should do), then this is a VERY cheap method (should cost less than $150 all said and done).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vho_GVXd5xs

Hopefully that's helpful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

Last month an app that does exactly that was banned from the App Store (read more [here](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57594896-37/iphone-screen-recording-app-slips-onto-the-app-store/)). So no official solution exists as of now.

Answer (score 0):

For jailbroken devices there are a couple of choices:

1. [RecordMyScreen](https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen) (which apparently works even with non-jailbroken devices, but not available from App Store!)
2. [Display Recorder](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.booleanmagic.displayrecorder) offers a lot of options, such as choosing video quality & format, scaling, showing tap locations in final video as well as when recording, etc.

Answer (score -1):

In general, no.  You can buy the [Apple iPad Dock Connector to VGA Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/A), but it will only work with applications designed to support it.  Most don't.

If there is a particular application you want to record, contact the developer of that app or check the documentation (if any) to see whether it supports video output.