# How can i see my iPad screen on a web browser

Tags: ipad, airplay

I'm looking for an application that enables me to preview my iPad screen, on a PC or Mac Desktop. Since I have a presenter on stage that will have an iPad in his hands, and I want to preview his screen on a giant screen behind him.

I was reading some of your answers, but the air play can't find it on either iPad store or Mac store! I'm willing to jailbreak the device if needed.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41979/can-i-record-ipad-screen-contents-over-airplay-to-an-apple-tv-and-then-recording

Answer (score 3):

Use [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/). It works on both PC and Mac, and it works great.

> Play games, watch movies, demo apps or present to your computer from your iPhone or iPad. Everything you do on the device is shown on the computer screen, wirelessly.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/), which is also available for Mac and PC.

> AirServer is an AirPlay receiver for Mac/PC. It allows you to receive
>   AirPlay feeds, similar to an Apple TV, so you can stream content or
>   Mirror your display from your iOS devices or Mountain Lion.